# C++ overriding the value of inherited static const variables

Tags: c++

I have a cpp class like this:

```
class A{
    protected:
      static const int _a = 0, _b = 0, _c = 0;
      std::string _data;
    public:
      void myMethod(); //method that changes _data based on the value of _a, _b and _c
};
```

If i want to create let's say:

```
Class B : public A{};
```

How do I change the values of `_a`, `_b` and `_c` in order to change the behavior of `myMethod`? Even if I declare them again, `myMethod` will still use the values form `class A` instead of `class B`.

Do I need to override the entire `myMethod` function if I want to change those 3 numbers?

EDIT: `myMethod()` is `public`, not `private`.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you call B::myMethod() explicitly ?

Comment: Those values are const so they can't change.

Comment: You can't change them, due to the fact that they are `const`. Hence - they can only be initialized.

Comment: Passing a few parameters to `myMethod` might influence its behavior.

Comment: Eeek. Leading underscores in identifier names make me cringe. As soon as someone chooses to change the first letter to a capital one you run afoul of the rule that names starting with underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation. Don't walk so close to the edge; just *don't* use leading underscores in names.

Comment: @xyious You would not be able to call `myMethod` in the manner that you suggest due to: 1) it being `private` method of `A` class; 2) Not being `static`.

Comment: Those values are `const` (presumably for a reason). Changing them would be ... bad ..  constants are not supposed to change after initialization (otherwise they wouldn't be `const`ants).

Comment: You can override virtual functions and nothing else.

Comment: You don't want to do this (and it isn't possible). Please review how inheritance and polymorphism work in C++. You want to override the function (made virtual). If need be, you could have additional virtual functions getA(), getB(), getC() that returned different constants for different subclasses.

Comment: You should read more on inheritance. When you declare a member `protect ` or `public`, The derived class has the same rights as the base one to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the value of constants as the name states `const`. You can only initialize them.

```
class A{
    protected:
        static const int val1, val2, val3;
    public:
        void myMethod();
};

const int A::val1 = 9;
const int A::val2 = 5;
const int A::val3 = 4;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly change the `const` static members, but perhaps what you want is `virtual` `getA(), getB(), getC()` methods.

Then your `A::myMethod()` implementation uses the getters rather than directly access to the static members.

In your `B` class, you can override the `get` methods to return different values (perhaps read from newly declared statics or whatever makes sense), and then `A::myMethod()` will automatically pick them up.